# не работает эхо бот почему? python

Tags: python, бот, telegram

```py
import config
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message : types.Message):    
    
        await message.answer(message.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Бот запускается, но не реагирует

Comment: У вас dp.message_handler() должно быть @bot.message_handler().

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в `dp.message_handler()`  а надо было `@dp.message_handler()`